# Action cable not working in rails 5.1.7 on production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable, ruby-on-rails-5.2, ruby-on-rails-5.1, redis-server

I using action cable with rails 5.1.7 and it's working fine in development env and production env on locally but when it's deployed on aws ec2 it's not working. Below is the production.rb code for action cable config.

```
config.action_cable.url = 'wss://example.com/cable'
config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = ["https://example.com", "https://www.example.com"]
config.action_cable.mount_path = '/cable/:token'
ActionCable.server.config.disable_request_forgery_protection = true
```

And cable.yml is mentioned below.

```
development:
  adapter: async

test:
  adapter: async

production:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1
```

but the default mounted path `get /cable` not calling at the server config level. If I'm calling wss://example.com/cable then it's connecting but default on page load it's not connecting.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the redis add-on, with the following. My code worked with this :

cable.yml

```
production:
    adapter: redis
    url: <%= ENV.fetch("REDISCLOUD_URL") { "redis://localhost:6379/1" } %>
    channel_prefix: _YourAppName_production
```

then, to install on production (mine was on heroku) :

```
heroku addons:create rediscloud:30
```

and I didn't need the action_cable setups in production.rb, it won't work if you leave 'myexample' expression as it is.